# How to map JSON values onto a different class with GSON

Tags: c#, java, json, gson

Ok, I figured out my original question which was a trivial naming issue, so I will repurpose this question for the actual problem.

I have a class in C#:

```
class Test
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize the class with System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer, I get:

```
{"Foo":"Bar"}
```

In java I have a class:

```
class Test
{
    private String foo;
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
```

I'm attempting to use GSON to parse the JSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Test test = gson.fromJson(getJson(), Test.class);
```

But I get null values.

How can I map the JSON values onto a slightly different class so I can still use best practice naming conventions in each language.

Comment: Major SRP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation...

Comment: @NatRitmeyer, an explanation of why you believe this to be the case would be useful to OP.

Comment: @spender, you're right, but I'm tired :) If I remember, I'll come back and write out an explanation tomorrow. Hopefully the OP will have taken a look at the above link by then and will spare me...

Comment: Didn't ask you to redesign the application. Please stay on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson by default uses the field names as-is, so your fields would need to be named `UpTime`, `ComputerName`, etc. From a Java naming perspective that would be blasphemous, though.

Keep your fields properly named in Java style as lower camel case and tell Gson to use [`FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#UPPER_CAMEL_CASE) instead:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
    .create();
Statistics stats = gson.fromJson(response.getJson(), Statistics.class);
```

Alternatively, you could adapt the C# side to output lower camel case `{"upTime" : ... }` of course.

Comment: This answers both the original and the new question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, didn't even see the new question. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the @SerializedName annotation, Example:

```
@SerializedName("Foo")
private String foo;
```