# How to parse a JSON string in to a name value pair in C#

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have to parse the `JSON` string in to a name value pair list :

```
{"vars":[
 {"name":"abcd","value":"true"},
 {"name":"efgh","value":"false"},
 {"name":"xyz","value":"sring1"},
 {"name":"ghi","value":"string2"},
 {"name":"jkl","value":"num1"}
 ],"OtherNames":["String12345"]}
```

I can not add the reference of `newtonsoft` JsonConvert due to multiple parties involved .

With `JavaScriptSerializer` i am able to get the `json` converted to name value only when i have one value in the `string` but not an `array`

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 Dictionary<string,string> dict = jsSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonText);
```

I think the declaration which says i will get the array values is missing somewhere.

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352695/how-to-map-json-values-onto-a-different-class-with-gson

Comment: http://json2csharp.com for all your conversion needs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deserialize that Json as `Dictionary<string, string>`. Because the json contains two different array and you should use complex object to deserialize it like this;

```
public class Var
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class SampleJson
{
    public List<Var> vars { get; set; }
    public List<string> OtherNames { get; set; }
}


JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var sampleJson = jsSerializer.Deserialize<SampleJson>(jsonText);
```

Comment: i am getting the error below when i tried to add this in :          
Type 'SampleJson' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
   at

Comment: Are you sure that json string which you are trying to deserialize is same with json which you shared in question ?

Comment: As the earlier error was invalid Array showing the "[" as the reason, i have  tried by removing the same. except that the json is "[" which are in between and left all of them in the same string

Comment: here is the string i used .. {"vars":[
 {"name":"abcd","value":"true"},
 {"name":"efgh","value":"false"},
 {"name":"xyz","value":"sring1"},
 {"name":"ghi","value":"string2"},
 {"name":"jkl","value":"num1"}
 ,"OtherNames":"String12345"}]

Comment: The json which you are trying to deserialize is wrong. Check it here; https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: That worked right away with the JSON String corrected.